# Realtime in Leaflet with Socket.io

Tags: leaflet, json, angularjs

I'm trying to get events on the client side and showing changes (new markers) in realtime on a leaflet map with socket.io.

The problem is in defining data that comes from socket.. I don't know the propriate way for getting data:

```
L.layerJSON({
   url: "msg"
```

I'm trying with `url` property, but it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('MapController', [ '$scope', '$http', '$interval', 'leafletData', 'socketio',  function($scope, $http, $interval, leafletData, socketio) {

        var map = L.map('map', {
            zoom: 8,
            layers: L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
            useCache: true
        });

        var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup().addTo(map);

        socketio.on('mapCoord', function (msg) {
            L.layerJSON({
                url: "msg",
                propertyLoc: ['latitude','longitude'],
                propertyTitle: 'name',
                minShift: Infinity,        
                caching: true,
                layerTarget: markers
            })
            .addTo(map);
        });

        map.addLayer(markers);
    }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L.layerJSON` does not exist! Read http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html !!

You probably want to create new instances of `L.Marker` by looping through the data received via websockets, and then doing something like `L.marker([msg.latitude, msg.longitude]).addTo(markers)` to add the new markers to your instance of `MarkerClusterGroup`.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Just to clarify `L.LayerJSON`; instead of geojson, I use data in json format and there is a [leaflet-layerJSON](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-layerJSON) library.